# Fragmentation in TLS

Tags: tls

I have a question related to the correct interpretation of RFC 5246 (TLS v1.2), in particular concerning the fragmentation in the record layer.

["6.2 Record Layer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2)" states that the record layer receives data from higher layers. "[6.2.1 Fragmentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.1)" states that multiple client messages of the same ContentType may be coalesced into a single record.

Is the word client in the cited part of 6.2.1 related to the client in the communication relationship of TLS client and TLS server or is it related to the client of the record layer in the implementation of the stack, which is the "higher layer" mentioned in 6.2?

Comment: My interpretation is that is indeed the record layer in the implementation of the stack. From the application point of view, once established the TLS connection is a stream of bytes and usually the application got no idea about TLS records or other implementation details.